# When will Dochan come to you in Blade and Soul?

Tags: blade-and-soul

I've been doing the starter quest for Blade and Soul, but while the quest says to meet Dochan at the "medical center" he doesn't come. I've seen him fighting "blackguard", but he doesn't come to me. I've been waiting for an hour playing another game but he doesn't come? What's wrong, or do I have to talk to someone else? I've tried the doctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dochan should enter the medical center a few seconds after you get in there. If he does not, try the following:

- cross the complete room (i.e. don't stop just right after the door)
- exit and re-enter the medical center
- exit the game, restart (you should be outside the medical center now) and re-enter